# Sonar app development for Android

Tags: android

In order to send a "ping" type signal from an Android phone and receive the signal via the built-in mic for spectrun analyses does one need to modify the phone's tranceiver to recover the carrier signal from the modulated frequency?

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending a modulated ping, then you need some way to recover the data, yes. If you're just using a simple audio ping, then no demodulation is needed.

Either way, you shouldn't need to modify the phone, it can be done in software with basic signal processing. If you're able to modulate a signal onto an audio tone, recovering it should be easily done.